# Converting a string to Timestamp with Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, timestamp

I am currently attempting to convert a column "datetime" which has values that are dates/times in string form, and I want to convert the column such that all of the strings are converted to timestamps.

The date/time strings are of the form "10/11/2015 0:41", and I'd like to convert the string to a timestamp of form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. At first I attempted to cast the column to timestamp in the following way:

df=df.withColumn("datetime", df["datetime"].cast("timestamp"))

Though when I did so, I received null for every value, which lead me to believe that the input dates needed to be formatted somehow. I have looked into numerous other possible remedies such as to_timestamp(), though this also gives the same null results for all of the values. How can a string of this format be converted into a timestamp?

Any insights or guidance are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import datetime

def to_timestamp(date_string):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

df = df.withColumn("datetime", to_timestamp(df.datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `to_timestamp` function. See [Datetime Patterns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) for valid date and time format patterns.

```
df = df.withColumn('datetime', F.to_timestamp('datetime', 'M/d/y H:m'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing it in the right way, except you missed to add the format of`string` type which is in this case `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`. Here `M` is used for `months` and `m` is used to detect `minutes`. Having said that, see the code below for reference -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('10/11/2015 0:41',), ('10/11/2013 10:30',), ('12/01/2016 15:56',)], ("String_Timestamp", ))
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("Timestamp_Format", to_timestamp(col("String_Timestamp"), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")).show(truncate=False)

+----------------+-------------------+
|String_Timestamp|   Timestamp_Format|
+----------------+-------------------+
| 10/11/2015 0:41|2015-10-11 00:41:00|
|10/11/2013 10:30|2013-10-11 10:30:00|
|12/01/2016 15:56|2016-12-01 15:56:00|
+----------------+-------------------+
```